# count the number of click in an interval of time

Tags: javascript, jquery, count, counter

how can I count the number of clicks in a time interval, for instace: how many clicks the user did in 2 seconds?? I know how to count clicks but I don't know how to measeure time

Thanks

Comment: Are you referring to any click whatsoever or do the clicks need to occur on a specific element?

Answer (score 1):

Try using a timeout to clear the function that detects the clicks. With jQuery, try this:

```
var clicks=0;
function myClickFunction(event){
    clicks++;
}
$(function(){
    $("#something").bind("click",myClickFunction);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#something").unbind("click",myClickFunction);
        alert("You clicked "+clicks+" times.");
    },2000);
});
```

Replace `#something` with a jQuery selector of an element you want the clicks to be detected on and the `alert` line with your own code that will be run after the timer has run out. 
Ad@m

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<button>Click me!</button>
<div id="status">Not Running</div>
```

JS:

```
var running = false,
    count = 0,
    run_for = 2000;

var end_counter = function() {
    if (running) {
        running = false;
        $("#status").text("Not Running");
        alert(count);
        started_at = 0;
    }
};
$('button').click(function() {
    if (running) {
        count++;
    } else {
        running = true;
        $("#status").text("Running");
        count = 1;
        setTimeout(end_counter, run_for);
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pXMxQ/2/

Answer (score 0):

Use the setTimeout function

e.g. if Every click increments a variable clickcount you could do the following:

```
 function startCounting(){
    clickcount = 0;
    setTimeout(function(){alert("you made "+clickcount +" clicks!");}, 2000);
 }
```

Comment: set clickcount = 0 in startCounting

Answer (score 0):

```
define a variable 
attach click handler to element 
set variable = 0
start ur timer (setTimeout)
increment variable on each click
when timeout handler excutes, detach ur handler

- OR - 

define a variable for counter
define a variable for doCounting
set counter = 0, doCounting = true
start ur timer (setTimeout)
increment counter on each click if doCounting is true
set doCounting = false when timeout handler executes
```